# Remove Action & Controller from url - EXT:news & RealURL

Tags: typo3, realurl

I'm having trouble removing /news/story/ from my URL's when using ext:news and real url.

What I'd like is:

www.mysite.com/en/news/this-is-my-story-title

And not:

www.mysite.com/en/news/story/this-is-my-story-title

Current page structure:

```
-root(1)
--Home (2)
--News (3)
---Story (4)
```

This is my manual realurl conf:

```
<?php

$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['addRootLineFields'] .= ',tx_realurl_pathsegment';

$domain = 'mysite.com';
$rootPageUid = 1;
$rssFeedPageType = 9818; // pageType of your RSS feed page

$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl'][$domain] = [
    'pagePath' => [
        'type' => 'user',
        'userFunc' => 'EXT:realurl/class.tx_realurl_advanced.php:&tx_realurl_advanced->main',
        'spaceCharacter' => '-',
        'languageGetVar' => 'L',
        'expireDays' => '3',
        'rootpage_id' => $rootPageUid,
        'firstHitPathCache' => 1
    ],
    'init' => [
        'enableCHashCache' => true,
        'respectSimulateStaticURLs' => 0,
        'appendMissingSlash' => 'ifNotFile,redirect',
        'adminJumpToBackend' => true,
        'enableUrlDecodeCache' => true,
        'enableUrlEncodeCache' => true,
        'emptyUrlReturnValue' => '/',
    ],
    'fileName' => [
        'defaultToHTMLsuffixOnPrev' => 0,
        'acceptHTMLsuffix' => 1,
        'index' => [
            'feed.rss' => [
                'keyValues' => [
                    'type' => $rssFeedPageType,
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],

    'preVars' => array(
        0 => array(
            'GETvar' => 'L',
            'valueMap' => array(
                'en' => 0,
                'cy' => 1,
            ),
            'noMatch' => 'bypass',
        ),
    ),

    'fixedPostVars' => array(
        'newsDetailConfiguration' => array(
            array(
                'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[action]',
                'valueMap' => array(
                    'story' => '',
                ),
                'noMatch' => 'bypass'
            ),
            array(
                'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[controller]',
                'valueMap' => array(
                    'news' => '',
                ),
                'noMatch' => 'bypass'
            ),
            array(
                'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[news]',
                'lookUpTable' => array(
                    'table' => 'tx_news_domain_model_news',
                    'id_field' => 'uid',
                    'alias_field' => 'title',
                    'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                    'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                    'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                        'strtolower' => 1,
                        'spaceCharacter' => '-'
                    ),
                    'languageGetVar' => 'L',
                    'languageExceptionUids' => '',
                    'languageField' => 'sys_language_uid',
                    'transOrigPointerField' => 'l10n_parent',
                    'autoUpdate' => 1,
                    'expireDays' => 180,
                )
            )
        ),
        'newsCategoryConfiguration' => array(
            array(
                'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[overwriteDemand][categories]',
                'lookUpTable' => array(
                    'table' => 'sys_category',
                    'id_field' => 'uid',
                    'alias_field' => 'title',
                    'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                    'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                    'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                        'strtolower' => 1,
                        'spaceCharacter' => '-'
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        'newsTagConfiguration' => array(
            array(
                'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[overwriteDemand][tags]',
                'lookUpTable' => array(
                    'table' => 'tx_news_domain_model_tag',
                    'id_field' => 'uid',
                    'alias_field' => 'title',
                    'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                    'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                    'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                        'strtolower' => 1,
                        'spaceCharacter' => '-'
                    )
                )
            )
        ),

        '4' => 'newsDetailConfiguration', // ID of the page with the news plugin detail view

    ),

    'postVarSets' => [
        '_DEFAULT' => [
            'controller' => [
                [
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[action]',
                    'noMatch' => 'bypass'
                ],
                [
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[controller]',
                    'noMatch' => 'bypass'
                ]
            ],

            'dateFilter' => [
                [
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[overwriteDemand][year]',
                ],
                [
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[overwriteDemand][month]',
                ],
            ],
            'page' => [
                [
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[@widget_0][currentPage]',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],

];
```

Using TYPO3 v8.7.15,RealURL 2.3 and News v7.0.4

RealUrl is set to use my manual conf file also.

Thanks again T3 community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

realUrl Provide pretty nice option to exclude a page from URL segment. For that go to `Page-> property->General`. You will find an option `Exclude from speaking URL` check this [Screenshot](https://prnt.sc/jsczox).

In your case go to `story` page and exclude this from URL

```
-root(1)
--Home (2)
--News (3)
---Story (4) // Exclude from realUrl
```

That's it, this what you're actually looking for!

Greetings!

Comment: Thank you for your response, unfortunately for some reason thats not working.

Comment: No error is thrown, initially it thought it was to do with this https://github.com/dmitryd/typo3-realurl/issues/367